# Get dictionary value from a List inside a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking to get the value of the description field inside the weather.

```
{'coord': {'lon': 73.85, 'lat': 18.52}, 'weather': [{'id': 800, 'main': 'Clear', 'description': 'clear sky', 'icon': '01d'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 305.381, 'pressure': 949.7, 'humidity': 31, 'temp_min': 305.381, 'temp_max': 305.381, 'sea_level': 1023.73, 'grnd_level': 949.7}
```

i have seen many posts and i am trying to do the below:

```
r1 = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Pune,in&APPID=5ad6ec2537bfb0d574363e115c2d0041')
print(r1.status_code)
json_data = json.loads(r1.text)
print(json_data)
print("Weather is" ,json_data["weather"][0])
```

But the above is fetching me all the values inside the dictionary. 
What's the best way to achieve that?
Thanks.

Comment: You already know how to get the value from a dictionary given a key, so what's the problem?

Comment: You didn't get the question, i want just the 'description': 'clear sky' and not everything inside the list

Comment: A side note: You can use [response.json()](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) method to get response as json.

Comment: No, I do get the question; you want the value for the key description from the dictionary you've accessed. What's confusing me is that your snippet already includes getting the value from a dictionary for the key weather, which could trivially be applied to your new situation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe okay..i am pretty new to it..still learning..u might be an expert. Anyways Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_data["weather"][0]['description']` to access the description field.

Comment: Thanks @J. Taylor.. Didn't know we can do that.

Comment: user3901666: `json_data["weather"][0]` refers to a dictionary object. The `['description']` part at the end is just retrieving an item from this dictionary. See: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries